# Getting list of IDs for RadiobuttonList on asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Need help with this as most of the answers related to this are not working for me.

I have an aspx file with the following:

```
<p><asp:RadioButtonList ID="id001" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server">
              <asp:ListItem class="radio-inline" Value="0" Text="None" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem class="radio-inline" Value="1" Text="Basic"></asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem class="radio-inline" Value="2" Text="Expert"></asp:ListItem>
              </asp:RadioButtonList></p>
```

and others with IDs "id002", "id003" and so on.

So I want to get a list of the RadioButtonList, and for each of those IDs, take an action.

I tried something like this on the aspx.cs:

```
foreach(Control c in Page.Controls)
            {


                        if (c.ID.Contains("id"))
                        {
                            string FullID = c.ID.ToString();
                            int StrippedID = Convert.ToInt32(FullID.Remove(0, 2));

                            string SQLSubmit = "INSERT INTO SkillData VALUES ('1', '01', '01', '01', '" + StrippedID + "' )";
                            SqlCommand Submit = new SqlCommand(SQLSubmit, SQLConn);
                            Submit.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        }

            }
```

I don't quite understand the way controls IDs are searched. When I debug the application, I can only see this if I dig deep down on variables, which is why I don't know how to reach it:

(App.Skill)(System.Web.UI.Control)(new System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView(c.Controls).Items[3])).Page).id001.ID    Value id001

Any help on how to address this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//If Page is with Master Page Add 
  Control form = Master.FindControl("form1");
  Control content1 = form.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1"); 
  //and Replace this with content1 in loop. Same with LINQ version

  foreach (Control c in content1.Controls)
 // Here this refers to Page Controls. If page is with MasterPage then first 
 //we need to go to parent container.
 //Let's say all your controls are inside of Panel, then you need to use 
 //panel1.Controls where panel1 is ID of Panel.
            {
            if (c is RadioButtonList)
            {
                if (c.ID.Contains("id"))
                {
                    string FullID = c.ID.ToString();
                }
            }
            }
```

If you want to use LINQ- Same with above version, first go to parent container

```
   foreach (Control c in this.Controls.OfType<RadioButtonList>())
            {

                if (c.ID.Contains("id"))
                {
                    string FullID = c.ID.ToString();
                }

            }
```

Let me know if it does not work.

Comment: I am not getting any ID value with this. One thing that I forgot to say is that this is a web form page with a master.page. I wonder if that throws the script off.

Comment: See updated answer. Let me know if it does not work.

Comment: Now I understand. And you are right, this works well!!. Thanks for the explanation and code.